# noexcept specifiers in function typedefs

Tags: c++, function-pointers, c++11, noexcept

Are noexcept specifiers accepted in function typedefs?

as in:

```
 typedef void (*fptr)()  noexcept;
```

Intuitively, noexcept specifiers seem to make sense since they would allow some optimisations at the caller's side.

I got a mixed answer from gcc 4.6.1.

```
 typedef void (*fptr)()  noexcept;
```

results in:
    error: ‘fptr’ declared with an exception specification

but:

```
template<void (*FPtr)()  noexcept>
struct A{};
```

compiles without warning.

Comment: In C++17 and later, exception specifications (aka. `noexcept`) are allowed in (member) function types as well as in function pointer and reference types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

clang gives:

```
test.cpp:1:25: error: exception specifications are not allowed in typedefs
typedef void (*fptr)()  noexcept;
                        ^
1 error generated.
```

This is backed up in the C++11 standard in 15.4 [except.spec]/p2:

> ... An *exception-specification* shall not appear in a typedef declaration
>   or *alias-declaration*.

Comment: Thanks. This probably makes accepting the noexcept-clause in the template-argument above a bug in gcc?

Comment: I don't think so.  [temp.param]/p4 says that non-type parameters can be a pointer to function and I don't see any mention of exception-specifications in that area.  And [except.spec]/p2 specifically says that an exception-specification can appear on a pointer to function.

Comment: Thanks again. I am a bit puzzled with this outcome, but there is no point in arguing with the standard.

Comment: @DirkM: The same problems were present with the `throw()` specifier, see [here](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm) for a nice example.

Comment: @Xeo: indeed. I checked and `trow()` is accepted at exactly the same spots as `noexcept`

Comment: @DirkM: Maybe because both are exception specifications? ;)

Comment: Note that one can still declare a typedef for a noexcept function pointer: `void dummy() noexcept; typedef decltype(dummy)* f_ptr_t;`. Working code can be found [here](https://ideone.com/Z0gMd9).